# Electronic signature on Ububtu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

Is it possible to electronically sign a document (I mean sign it without printing and scanning the whole file) under Ubuntu 16.04? And how do I install it?

**EDIT** To be clear I want to *electronically* sign my document not *digitally*: I want to put my actual signature on the document witout having to print and scannign it

Comment: What I did was: sign a blank piece of paper, scan that, and use GIMP to create a .png file with a transparent background. You can open e.g. a PDF file in GIMP or LibreOffice Draw and insert the signature file in the desired place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Put your signature on a blank piece of paper.
2. Scan the paper.
3. Use GIMP to create a .png file with your signature in black on a transparent background.
4. Export the .png file and save it in a secure location.

Now every time you need to sign a document, open it in GIMP or LibreOffice Draw. Also open the signature file and insert it in the desired place.